# How can I find out the absolute path of Vim in Git Bash?

Tags: git, bash, vim

I am using Git Bash in Windows 10 and would like to find out the absolute path of Vim, such that I can add the folder in the environment variable PATH and therefore I can use Vim in cmd.

In Linux, we can type something like "whereis vim" to find out the absolute path, but in Git Bash the "whereis" command doesn't work.

I also tried to find by searching the folders with keywords, and also tried to find the Vim folder manually in program files or user folder, but also can't identify the folder location.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the finder in windows (the little search icon at the bottom left of the desktop) and type 'vim' then left click > properties.

Comment: Problem finally solved by adding "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" in the environment variable PATH. Many thanks~!

Before adding the path, in the search box there is no result of vim.exe (I don't know why).

But after adding, since that becomes a command of cmd, now it is searchable.

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest command (from [Wikipedia `whereis` page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whereis)) in Windows is (under bash) `/c/Windows/System32/where.exe`.

But that will search against the `$PATH`, which mean vim would need to be in $PATH, and could be called directly.

That means the unix command '`which`' is enough.

Since vim *is* packaged with Git (in the `etc` folder of a Git installation folder), I see in my Git bash on Windows 10:

```
vonc@voncavn7:/c$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
vonc@voncavn7:/c$ ls -alrth /usr/bin/vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Mar 30  2017 /usr/bin/vim -> /etc/alternatives/vim
```

`/etc` means `<folder where Git is installed>/etc/alternatives/vim>`

`/etc/alternatives/vim` in turn points to `/usr/bin/vim.basic`.

```
vonc@voncavn7:/etc/alternatives$ l vim
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Mar 30  2017 vim -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
```

That means `vim` is actual in `<folder where Git is installed>\usr\bin\vim.basic`.

Comment: in my computer I don't have "/etc/alternatives/vim", but I do have "/usr/bin/vim".

Thus I added "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" in my environment variable and now I can use vim in cmd.

Many thanks~!

Just curious, what is "/mnt/t/test$" in your command? I don't have /mnt/ in my folder. I can just directly run "which vim" in my git bash.

Comment: @HMC What version of Git are you using? I have edited my answer to explain what `/etc` refers to. And forget about `/mnt/t`: it is just a local disk I have. I have edited it out of the answer.

Comment: Many thx. I am using Git 2.8.1, and that was installed together with Heroku. I have `C:\Program Files\Git\etc` but I don't have `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\alternatives`

Comment: @HMC Git 2.8.1 sounds old. Any change you could upgrade to 2.16.1? (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases)

Comment: I did install the latest Git. But when I install Heroku, it had an old Git 2.8.1 inside already. As I am totally new to Git/Heroku, I'm not sure whether the two versions will "crash". Thus I uninstall the standalone latest Git, and kept the old Git inside Heroku (cos I think this old Git may corporate with Heroku better).

Comment: N.B. the powershell has the alias `where` for `Where-Object`.

Comment: @Polluks Agreed. I don't think PowerShell is needed for this question though.

Answer (score 3):

In Vim 8, you can just query a special built-in constant:

```
:echo v:progpath
O:\tools\vim\vim.exe
```